# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

Can someone explain what I'm seeing in the shell output below please:

```
import test/models.py

biz_area = BusinessArea.objects.filter(business_area_manager=user)

dprint(biz_area)
[{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x3726890>,
'business_area_id': Decimal('42'),
'business_area_manager': Decimal('999'),
'business_area_name': u'group 1',
'inactive': u'N'}]

biz_area.business_area_id

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<<console>console>", line 1, in <<module>module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'business_area_id'
```

So, python is saying that the biz_area queryset has no 'business_area_id' attribute when the pretty printed listing of the object shows that it does have such an attribute. Can someone put me on the right track here as this is confusing me somewhat...

Comment: What about `biz_area['business_area_id']`?

Comment: @Matthias that wouldn't work as `biz_area` is a collect of objects

Comment: You're right of course. I should have used my other glasses to look at the question ...

Answer (score 6):

`biz_area` is `QuerySet` object.  This is a collection not a single object.

```
[{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x3726890>,
'business_area_id': Decimal('42'),
'business_area_manager': Decimal('999'),
'business_area_name': u'group 1',
'inactive': u'N'}]
```

The brackets ([]) denote a collection. You could think of this in terms as a python list

There are a couple ways of handling this:

filter will always return a colletion of objects

```
biz_areas = BusinessArea.objects.filter(business_area_manager=user)
for biz_area in biz_areas:
  biz_area.business_area_id
```

If `BusinessArea` will only ever have one associate `user`

```
biz_area = BusinessArea.objects.get(business_area_manager=user)
biz_are.business_area_id
```

read the documentation regarding [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) it will raise exceptions if there are more objects, or 0 objects matching your query

Answer (score 0):

Wrong, the pretty print of `biz_area` doesn't show that it has `business_area_id` attribute and it would be strange if it had it, as the queryset is a collection of objects (visible as a list in the pretty print though it's not a list actually) and `business_area_id` is an attribute of a single object.

Answer (score 0):

biz_area is Queryset object, means it is collection of objects.
Loop over biz_area to get business_area_id.

```
for i in biz_area:
  i.business_area_id
```

Answer (score -1):

if you type

```
type(biz_area)
```

you'll see it's a list type, not an object from a queryset. You have to iterate through all the items in your biz_area variable and print them out.

If you [retrieved a single object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) you could then access its business_area_id attribute like you did.

Comment: biz_area is a django.db.models.query.QuerySet